# how to add missing "Wireless Network (IEEE 802.11) Policies" to group policy

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, security, group-policy

I have a laptop with "Windows 7 Professional" installed.  It is going to be used by someone for whom I must carefully control interned access.  For many reasons, I want to do this using group policy editor.  (Please don't say "you shouldn't be trying to control access", or "just do it this other way" - I have omitted many many pertinent details for reasons of privacy, and without knowing and understanding all the details, you cannot judge.)

In particular, I need to set up group policy in "Wireless Network (IEEE 802.11) Policies" (under "Security Settings") for the user.

However, when I run the group policy editor, there is no "Wireless Network (IEEE 802.11) Policies" node.  Everything I can find on the web either assumes the node is there, or is geared towards and enterprise environment with a DC.

How can I add this policy to the "Security Settings" in the group policy editor?  Thanks.